# How can I reset modal-content every time the modal is hidden (removeData() didn't work)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS 1.4.0.

If I use `remote` feature to load modal content, I need to `$compile` it, but `removeData()` won't work in this situation, as it won't work either when writing modal content in the dom.

#### sample.html

```
<div id="saveModal" class="modal inmodal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" refresh-modal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Content here or remote -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### script.js

```
.directive("refreshModal", ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e) {
                $compile(element.contents())($scope);
            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                element.removeData('bs.modal');
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Resetting the form is not enough, because there are some other texts in the modal content that don't belong to the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

This project was crested by the angular team and play much nicer with Angular Apps.

You will go through much less pain than trying to get Bootstrap JS components to work nicely with Angular.